# How to keep track of everything with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, audit

I was wondering how I could keep track of what's going on with entities, like who created the user, when, when was it last accessed ?

More than that, I would also like to know about previous changes. to keep it simple I'd like to keep track of every changes.

Is there a solution for that ?

edit :

For Hibernate : we can use Envers that seems to cover the needs

Comment: Check out the [Hibernate ORM Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) project. This enables `easy auditing/versioning of persistent classes`. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed It seems to be what I'm looking for, is there something like Envers for other JPA implementations ?

Comment: There might be some but frankly I am aware of alternatives. As auditing is not part JPA spec it is up to the implementors.

Comment: thanks for your time ! it has been very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the [Hibernate ORM Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) project. This enables easy auditing/versioning of persistent classes.

> Regarding, there something like Envers for other JPA implementations

There might be some but, frankly, I am aware of other alternatives. As auditing is not part JPA spec, it is up to the implementors.

A quick search has yielded following link [EclipseLink HistoryPolicy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History) which looks similar to Envers but for eclipseLink.